# Native-base not working with react-native 0.57.1?

Tags: react-native, native-base

**Using** :

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.57.1
- native-base: ^2.9.2

**What I have done** :

1 : expo-cli init test

When prompted, I chose to create a blank project.

2 : cd test

3 : npm install --save native-base

4 : npm install --save @expo/vector-icons

Then I import and use native-base Text component in App.js

Here is the error I get when building the app :

*Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome5" from "node_modules/native-base/dist/src/basic/IconNB.js"*

Any suggestion or is it a known issue ? Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: I'm also facing this problem exactly right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eureka !

I downgraded native base to version to 2.8.2 and it works.

```
npm install --save native-base@2.8.2
```

Found it here : https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/857

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-native link native-base` it will start working on your side, no need to downgrade.

it will work

Comment: It doesn't :(   : Error: Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null.   Did it work for you ?

Comment: Might be your react native version is old. 

I ended up running `react-native upgrade` afterwards, an iOS and android folder appeared and my issues were gone.

your issue will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

one more step !
type *react-native link* in cmd

Comment: Does not work for me : Error: Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null
Beside, I would like to continue using expo in dev.

Comment: There is a problem with react or react native core

Comment: Try re installing your react native project

Answer (score 1):

Solved (kind of) in @expo/vector-icons v8.1.0.

See https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/58#issuecomment-450015936

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the version often there are problem for new release of components. Choose stable one first and then increment it gradually during project

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for which version ?  Do I just have to npm uninstall and the re-install with new version number or are there a specific process to follow for downgrading ?